# Is there any AdMob dummy id?

Tags: android, admob

Is there any AdMob dummy ids for testing purpose? 
Do I need to register app & get MY_AD_UNIT_ID?

Comment: What platform is this for? Android?

Comment: You are making the call through an Activity or from XML?

Comment: here is appId 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713'

Answer (score 57, accepted):

This is the **dummy id for Banner ads**.

> ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111

[source](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner)

Answer (score 49):

Banner:

```
ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111
```

Interstitial:

```
ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712
```

Rewarded Video:

```
ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917
```

Native Advanced:

```
ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2247696110
```

Native Advanced Video:

```
ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1044960115
```

Native Express Small/Large:

```
ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2793859312 
ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2177258514
```

[source](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads)

Answer (score 21):

OS: Android

Mediation: Admob

**For Banner Ads:**

```
ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111
```

[Source](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/tree/master/admob/BannerExample)

**For Interstitial Ads:**

```
ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712
```

[Source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/interstitial)

**For Admob NativeExpress Ads:**

```
ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1072772517
```

**For Rewarded Video**

```
ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917
```

**Note:**

> The  NativeExpressAd you'll see looks like a real one, but it's counted as a test
>   ad. You're free to use that ad unit ID for your testing.

**by Andrew Brogdon** (Google Ads Team in one of his youtube comments)

[image]

All test Ads you can find in the actual [admob github repository](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/tree/master/admob) in the res > values > strings.xml

Comment: Hi Dinesh, Could you please help me with this. I've created an account and used my Unit ID but not getting any ad.

Comment: Could you open a new question and put a xml and java code of ad unit..And you can tag me there.

Comment: I've used NativeExpressAdView  and using unit id of banner and it works fine.  is this the proper solution? if not then i'll open a new question with code. Thanx.

Comment: also posted a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40671219/nativeexpressadview-not-working-with-native-ad-unit-id-but-does-work-with-banner

Comment: Rewarded Video: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917

Answer (score 17):

And sample app id for tests : ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713

Comment: Why isnt this mentioned in the documentation of AdMob when they are telling us all about the dummy TestUnit Ids !?!?

Answer (score 7):

There aren't dummy ID's per se. You need to setup the XML or the JAVA code to get test ads. To get *Test Ads* during testing, add the following to your XML where you have the `AdView` declared.

NOTE: I use just the XML code to display Ads in my app.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom|center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="YOUR_AD_UNIT_ID"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
        ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, YOUR_DEVICE_ID" >
    </com.google.ads.AdView>
</LinearLayout>
```

To set the Test Unit (Both the emulator and your devices) from JAVA:

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);            
adRequest.addTestDevice("test");
```

To get your Device ID, you can use this:

```
final TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String deviceid = tm.getDeviceId();
```

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9681517/450534

*EDIT: Missed your second question.*

Yes. You will need to register your app in your Ad-Mob account. Without that being registered, you won't be getting your Ad Unit ID and therefore, no Ads in your app either.

**UPDATE:** Approximately two years after posting this answer, Google added a few dummy ID's to their admob SDK. Please refer to the other better voted answers for the dummy ID's

Comment: this answer should be update, admob now offers dummy ids `ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111`

Answer (score 5):

Here is an official update from google

**Android**

- Banner: `ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111`
- Interstitial : `ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712`
- Reward Video: `ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917`
- Native Advanced: `ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2247696110`
- Native Express (small): `ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2793859312`
- Native Express (large): `ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2177258514`

**IOS**

- Banner:`ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111`
- Interstitial `ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712`
- Rewarded Video   `ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1712485313`
- Native Advanced  `ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2247696110`
- Native Express   (Small): `ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4270592515`
- Native Express(Large): `ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/8897359316`

Read more:

- [Android Test Ads on Firebase](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads)
- [IOS Test Ads on Firebase](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads)

Answer (score 4):

For `RewardedVideo` you can use the following one :

```
private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917";
private static final String APP_ID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713";
```

how to use:

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, APP_ID);

mRewardedVideoAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
mRewardedVideoAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(this);
mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd(AD_UNIT_ID, new AdRequest.Builder().build());
```

for showing

```
 if (mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
        mRewardedVideoAd.show();
  }
```

Hope this will help many of us!

Answer (score 3):

Sample adMob by google

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Comment: where to put these lines?