# NativeExpressAdView not working with native ad unit id but does work with banner unit ad

Tags: java, android

i've integrated admob in my project and according to requirement i am using **NativeExpressAdView** to show native ads. But it doesn't work with native's unit ID. But its working find when i add banner's unit ID in **NativeExpressAdView** as follow:

XML code:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView
                    android:id="@+id/adView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_id_banner"
                    ads:adSize="FULL_WIDTHx220
</com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView>
```

Java code:

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
//.addTestDevice("6D446467FCE9EB26F0F478F9B93230AC")
.build();
adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAdClosed() {
        super.onAdClosed();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdFailedToLoad(int i) {
        super.onAdFailedToLoad(i);
        String mErrorCode = "default";
        switch (i){
            case AdRequest.ERROR_CODE_INTERNAL_ERROR:
            mErrorCode = "internal error";
            break;
            case AdRequest.ERROR_CODE_INVALID_REQUEST:
            mErrorCode = "invalid request";
            break;
            case AdRequest.ERROR_CODE_NETWORK_ERROR:
            mErrorCode = "network error";
            break;
            case AdRequest.ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL:
            mErrorCode = "no fill";
            break;
        }
        Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, String.format("onAdFailedToLoad(%S)",mErrorCode), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdLeftApplication() {
        super.onAdLeftApplication();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdOpened() {
        super.onAdOpened();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded() {
        super.onAdLoaded();
    }
});
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

It always shows "internal error" when i use Native unit id. but if i use banner id in **NativeExpressAdView** it works fine.

Is this the proper solution to use banner unit id in **NativeExpressAdView**? and what could be reason for this?

Comment: NativeADS Will be shown only if you mention perfect AdSize. Try out different sizes. for example look in this docs https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/NativeExpressAdView

Comment: When ever you are testing NativeAds for the first time Try to test in your mobile by landscape mode.Some times width also may be the problem and NativeAd may not appear.