# Using Admob for testing vs live

Tags: android, admob

I am finishing up my first app which includes Admob. I have entered my ad unit ID and it is working perfect. I am currently on beta testing, so in order to see 'test' adds, I added my own device using the recommended method:

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
.addTestDevice("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx").build();
```

I have 2 questions:

1. For Beta testing, how can I prevent my testers to see the live ads without knowing their device IDs?
2. For go-live, do I have to remove the `addTestDevice()` calls so I can see the real thing?

What is the usual procedure ?

Answer (score 0):

> For Beta testing, how can I prevent my testers to see the live ads
>   without knowing their device IDs?

You have to know their device id, otherwise they will see real ads. However, you can get device id programatically to put it in `addTestDevice()` method. [See this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681400/android-get-device-id-for-admob)

> For go-live, do I have to remove the addTestDevice() calls so I can
>   see the real thing?

It is not necessary to remove the `addTestDevice()`. But if you want to see real ads then yes it is necessary; though it is better to not remove `addTestDevice()`, that's how you can prevent yourself from accidentally clicking ads.