# AdMob Android SDK Testing

Tags: android, admob

I have a bunch of test devices for my app, and I'd rather not have to manually enter all of the device ids for admob testing. I am using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18114634/691639) to get the device id if my debugging flag is set.

My question is, if I add a device to admob testing, is that permanent or only for the duration of that ad session? I'm worried that if I accidentally publish my app with the debug flag, no real ads will be delivered to my users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring a device to be a test device only has lifespan of that AdRequest.

But in any case unless your users all have devices with that DeviceId it wouldn't matter.

Comment: I am actually generating what would be that device's id on the fly.