# Is it normal for Android app with ads ask for device ID?

Tags: android, security, admob

I have noticed that for few apps containing ads, they will ask for `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission. After tracking down their bytecode, I find they call `TelephonyManager.getDeviceId()`. Is it necessary for app containing ads ask for DeviceID? It's malicious to me because it seems that these apps will leak my private information.

Comment: "Necessary" is going to be very subjective here, but my immediate reaction is this is some form of "tracking"

Comment: Thanks for commenting! lc. The "necessary" here means "is Ads library like Admob require information such as DeviceID"? If it's something that developer can avoid, I would regard it as not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Admob at least doesn't require that permission. All it needs is Internet access permission.

I can't tell if other providers require more permissions.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I do see some [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4524752/how-can-i-get-device-id-for-admob) asking how to get deviceID for Admob. I'm wondering why do they need it.

Comment: This is most likely because people want to put their own devices into test mode and they need device id.