# How to get Device id for Admob

Tags: android, admob

i added admob ad in my application,
the device id required for admob i find by following code,

```
String android_id = Settings.Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
device_id = md5(android_id).toUpperCase();

public static String md5(String s) {
    try {

        MessageDigest digest = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        digest.update(s.getBytes());
        byte messageDigest[] = digest.digest();


        StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i=0; i<messageDigest.length; i++)
            hexString.append(Integer.toHexString(0xFF & messageDigest[i]));
        return hexString.toString();

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

The problem with this is that its showing ads on some devices but on some devices it shows test ads. where am i wrong?? pls help

Comment: Device id required only for showing test ads,not in deployment.

Comment: so, what should i pass as parameter in "device_id"  
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
     .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
     .addTestDevice(device_id)
     .build();
//  adView.loadAd(adRequest);

Comment: do you want to display test ad?

Comment: no i want to implement admob in my app and upload it to play store so that any user downloads my app from play store admob should work on all those devices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`addTestDevice` is used for showing Admob test ads for development.so in deployment remove `addTestDevice` from your `adRequest`,i.e. make your `adRequest`  as

```
   AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
   adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

And if you want to get device id for testing then see this 
[How can I get device ID for Admob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4524752/how-can-i-get-device-id-for-admob)
Then add `addTestDevice` in `adRequest` as

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(device_id)
                .build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Comment: @RajeshSuthar Happpy to help,enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

It is mentioned on the official tutorial page with link -  https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/banner
That

logcat will print the device's MD5-hashed ID for convenience, for example: 
   Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("AC98C820A50B4AD8A2106EDE96FB87D4") to get test ads on this device.

Means your device ID will be similarly shown. The above one is just an example id.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to your Log Cat and search "Ads".
Then you will find your device then just use it like.

```
AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
.addTestDevice("Device ID")
.build();
```