# Handling test/production "Ad Unit ID" in admob android application

Tags: android, admob

I'm making an application including admob ads with help of this [google's official tutorial](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start?hl=fr)

However, it states "You should always use test ads when developing and testing your app--testing with live production ads is a violation of AdMob policy and could cause your account to be suspended".

So I now have a test and a production Ad Unit ID. Should I manually switch my code to production/test id during my application release process or is there an kind of automatic for this?

Thank you

Comment: please tell me how did you got an ad unit id for production?

Comment: You'll get it from your admob account:
https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3052638

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the production Ad Unit ID for your testing.
just include the test device and it'll automatically load the test ads.

```
private static final String TEST_DEVICE ="xxxx..."; //see Log cat for the value.

AdRequest adrequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .addTestDevice(TEST_DEVICE)
            .build();

if (adview !=null)
       adview.loadAd(adRequest);
```

see this post on how to get the TEST_DEVICE id [How can I get device ID for Admob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4524752/how-can-i-get-device-id-for-admob)

Comment: I am testing production Ad Unit ID on real android device. Do I need to use .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR) line or remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to switch ad IDs for test and production when making a build. You can simply put this code and it'll switch test unit ID if you are in debug mode and production when you make a 'release':

```
String intersProd_ID="<your admob production ID";
String intersTest_ID="<admob test unit ID";
String useInters;

        if((BuildConfig.DEBUG)){
            useInters = intersTest_ID;
        }
        else{
            useInters = intersProd_ID;
        }
```