# Can the Device id for two Android phones/device be same?

Tags: android

Also Does the Device id change? If yes when?

(Used for Test Ads in addTestDevice() in adbuilder)

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(DEVICE_ID)
                .setRequestAgent("android_studio:ad_template").build();
```

Comment: what is DEVICE_ID

Comment: It is a string 
 addTestDevice("D9XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

Comment: you can see the link to know about the device id https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4524752/how-can-i-get-device-id-for-admob

Comment: Read this question's each **answers and comments**, you will understand this concept of **ID**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id

Comment: The device id is returned by the 05-31 20:17:23.505 26518-26518/? I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("D9XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX") to get test ads on this device.

Comment: in the logcat when the ad is seen.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're thinking of IMEI. The answer is `maybe`, its not guaranteed to be universally unique.

But, more on your point, Google has published their own official [Best practices for unique identifiers](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids). For your use case, identifying the device for advertising purposes, there's a [AdvertisingIdClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient) that you should use.

Comment: No not the IMEI number

Comment: The id we get in the logcat when view the ad 05-31 20:17:23.505 26518-26518/? I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("D9XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX") to get test ads on this device.